# Why do I need an IIF when returning a boolean in an SSRS expression?

Tags: reporting-services, boolean, iif, ssrs-expression

Basically my question is why can't I write an expression that expects a boolean like

```
=Parameters!.Param1.Value = 3
```

Instead you have to explicitly return true or false like

```
=IIF(Parameters!Param1.Value = 3, True, False)
```

Does the expression `Parameters!.Value = 3` evaluate to an integer (i.e. 1 or 0)? What's going on here?

Comment: It looks like, as @BrianPressler pointed out, that both expressions work. All examples I've seen use IIF and even chain them together into ugly monstrosities. I could have sworn the non-IIF way has failed for me in the past, but I guess it could have been a legitimate bug instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can have a boolean comparison in an expression.  Where are you finding that you can't use it?  What is the error message you are getting?

Also, neither of your expressions in your question are valid because they are missing the parameter name.  It should look more like:

```
=Parameters!MyBoolParameter.Value = 3
```

Maybe that is the cause of the error you are getting?

Comment: The missing parameter name was just a mistake in the example. It looks like you are correct about both working. I could have sworn the non-IIF statement failed for me on a Visibility expression, but I can't reproduce it in a test report.

Answer (score 0):

That's syntax. If you find your expression complex, you can implement a custom function in report code then call it from your report.